# How can I control single and double quotes in string transfers from PHP to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to copy strings that have escaped single and double quotes from PHP to JavaScript. When I get the string having escaped quotes on the server into JavaScript the escape back-slashes are gone.

Ultimately I'm trying to transfer JSON from the server to the client JavaScript. The string values in the JSON may have single or double quotes.
I have to use single quotes to denote the string literal on the client because JSON is full of double quotes. That means all single quotes in the string must be escaped.

```php
<?php 
  $s = "this\'s a test";
  echo $s;
?>
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      console.log('<?= $s?>'); //displays: this's a test
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

edit per ADyson
The echoed string in PHP (below) shows the escape on the single quote removed.
The double quote is double escaped this time (3 back slashes).

What console.log (below) is displaying is not valid JSON.
I can't control it.

**How can I transfer the object $obj to an identical obj in Javascript?**

[PHP Sandbox code below test](https://onlinephp.io/c/fc536)

```
$str = 'Johnny\'s back yard has a sign that says \"NO SHOUTING!\". We\'re \"NOT\" SHOUTING!';
$obj = (object)["Name"=>"The big Test", "Str" => $str];
$s = json_encode($obj);
echo $s;
?>
<html><body><script>
console.log('<?= $s?>');  //This crashes
var obj = JSON.parse('<?= $s?>'); //This is never executed but would crash.
</script></body></html>
```

Comment: The backslash escapes are **never** actually part of the string. They're "eaten" when the string constant is parsed.  If you want to have a backslash in a string, you have to double it, which will leave your string value with just one of them.

Comment: Have you tried backticks? ``?

Comment: To echo what Pointy said: Data is data. The slashes are only necessary for the programmer to express the correct data.

Comment: `I'm trying to transfer JSON`...where? There's no JSON in your example code. Please provide a [mre] of the real issue.

Comment: Pointy: my experience is that if I add a backtick, in the client string I get a double backtick. I seem to be able to get no backtick or 2 backticks but not 1 backtick.

Comment: Re your update: To get the output you're expecting, write `console.log(JSON.stringify(<?= $s?>))` instead. https://jsfiddle.net/L4np5802/ . If you make a JSON string which contains single quotes, and then try put that into a string literal enclosed by single quotes, then naturally that will be problematic. But that's an entirely confected and unnecessary scenario. Since JSON can be interpreted by JS as an _object_ literal, better to let it treat it like that, and then have it encode it back to valid JSON if/when necessary. That way you're not accidentally interfering with the process.

Comment: `my experience is that if I add a backtick`...do you mean "backslash". Backtick and backslash are different things.

Comment: Are you saying do this? var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(<?= json_encode($obj)?>));

Comment: Sorry, yea backslash

Comment: No, I'm saying to do what I said to do

Comment: If you want to make an object instead of logging, just `var obj = <?= $s?>;` is sufficient

Comment: I don't believe it. It worked. I have a duplicate object on the client. I've fought with this for years. Thanks so much.

Comment: No problem. Remember JS can read JSON as an object literal. JSON syntax is a subset of object literal syntax (hence the acronym)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to make a JS object from your PHP string which contains JSON, just

```
var obj = <?= $s?>;
```

is sufficient. Remember JS can read JSON as an object literal. JSON syntax is a subset of JavaScript object literal syntax.